# How to insert multiple rows without losing performance SQLITE + C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1

> My applicantion needs to insert 221 rows when it started by 1st time, so, i am losing performance because i am using arrays to insert it. for exemple.

```
 private async Task insereHinos()
    {
        var local = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "hinos.sqlite");
        SQLiteAsyncConnection con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(local, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
        await con.CreateTableAsync<hinos>();

        variaveis variavel = new variaveis();
        for (var i = 0; i < 221; i++)
        {
            var hino = new hinos() { numHino = variavel.numeroHinos[i], favHino = variavel.favHinos, nomeHino = variavel.nomeHinos[i], catHino = variavel.categoriaHinos[i], letraHino = variavel.letraHinos[i] };
            await con.InsertAsync(hino);

        }

    }
```

> In this way, i am losing performance a lot ,so, How can I use other way to fix it.

Comment: can you use the `StringBuilder` class to build the sql statement along with `string.Format` function to insert the values inside of a foreach loop..?

Comment: Ok, i will search about this.. Did you hear about RunInTransactionAsync ?

Comment: Wrap your inserts in a transaction. Just send a `BEGIN` query before inserting the values and an `END` query afterwards.

Comment: @SplittyDev Now, i am searching about the method... RunInTransactionAsync method... but i dont know how to use... the concept is... start a transaction > insert values > end transaction ?

Comment: I'll give you an example: `BEGIN; INSERT INTO something (x, y) VALUES (1, 2); ... more insertions here ...; END;`

Comment: If you want it asynchronously, just do `con.RunInTransactionAsync (transaction => { /* Insertions here */ }});`
Insert using `transaction.Insert (...);`

Comment: @SplittyDev i did this... await con.RunInTransactionAsync(transaction => { transaction.InsertAsync(hino); }); ... the performance has improved a lot.. i  was waiting more than 20 second in the first screen, now i am waiting 2 seconds because a timer screen.

Comment: @SplittyDev now i learned a thing.... for exemple.. method (action => {action.sqlmethod(object value)})

Comment: @HenriqueAlbuquerque You don't need the `transaction.InsertAsync` since you're already in an asynchronous transaction. Just use `transaction.Insert`.